# Codegen error while creating an exe/building in PowerBuilder 7

Tags: powerbuilder, powerbuilder-build-deploy

Friends,

While building an application to create an exe..i am getting the below error...in the log file..

```
Codegen compilation error, see file 'C:\DOCUME~1\PA\LOCALS~1\Temp\cietadmin.log'.
```

The cietadmin.log contains the below entries.

```
    CGEN: Compiling 'C:\DOCUME~1\PA\LOCALS~1\Temp\cietadmin.c'
C:\DOCUME~1\PA\LOCALS~1\Temp\cietadmin.c(21) function argument(s) do not match those in prototype 
C:\DOCUME~1\PA\LOCALS~1\Temp\cietadmin.c(21) 'unsigned stdcall (__export FN_RunExecutable)( HINSTANCE__ const *, HINSTANCE__ const *, wchar_t *, int, wchar_t *, int )' defined in: d:\Program Files\Sybase\Shared\PowerBuilder\cgen\EN32T.h(1) (col 1) 
C:\DOCUME~1\PA\LOCALS~1\Temp\cietadmin.c(21) cannot convert argument 3 defined in: C:\DOCUME~1\PA\LOCALS~1\Temp\cietadmin.c(22) (col 49) 
C:\DOCUME~1\PA\LOCALS~1\Temp\cietadmin.c(21) source conversion type is "char * (lvalue)" 
C:\DOCUME~1\PA\LOCALS~1\Temp\cietadmin.c(21) target conversion type is "wchar_t *"
```

What might be the problem? How can i solve it?
I have reinstalled the PB software but no use.

Thanks & regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My first suggestion would be to examine why you're building to machine code. I've written a [rather long diatribe](http://www.techno-kitten.com/PowerBuilder_Help/Troubleshooting/Machine_Code/machine_code.html) on how machine code benefits very select cases, and is known to present challenges.

The other suggestion is to make the case that, if you're leaving yourself dependent for peer support, your team should move up to a more current / more used version of PowerBuilder. PB7 is pretty Y2K.

Good luck,

Terry.

Comment: First of all...Thanks for your kind help. now its working...Actually i am new to powerbuilder. originally i am a vb6 developer. my company is already using this software which was developed by a person using powerbuilder 7. Now he left the company. So  i am taking care of this software. whenever they need any changes or new form or reports, i have to develop using this version of software. i am just googling and doing the changes in this software.i have few more doubts. when ever i create a new form or report, am i have to build the application with full or incremental rebuild or regenerate?

Comment: I recommend a full build to deploy the application. For development other than DataWindows, if you change an object's "footprint", that is adding/removing methods or instance variables, or changing a method signature, do an incremental build. If you make changes to a DataWindow that's used as a child DataWindow (composite, DDDW), regenerate any DataWindows that have it as a child. If PB is acting strange, such as events not firing or runtime errors for objects that aren't found, restart PowerBuilder then do a full rebuild. If a rebuild fails you have no choice but migrate or use backup PBLS.

Comment: If you __only__ change the code inside a method, you shouln't need to rebuild or regenerate anything to run in the IDE. I hope you have your PowerBuilder objects under version control. If not I'd make it a top priority. Especially if you're working on unfamiliar code, you need to be able to go back to an earlier version. Don't use ObjectCycle, it's not real VC. For a no-cost solution you can use SVN and PBSCC Proxy.